# .htaccess images not showing after rewriting

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem, URL's have been rewritten like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?test=$1 [NC,L]
```

None of my images, nor css styles are being applied. I have tried `<base href="/">`, but it is not working.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
## if the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?test=$1 [NC,L]
```