# htaccess Change the root folder for one of my domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

htaccess Change the root folder for one of my domain.

My Current Url is Like This

```
domain.com/theme/
```

I want to like this

```
domain.com/
```

Please Share Your Valuable Answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, any website is loaded from the public_html folder. I'm assuming that you have a folder inside the public_html folder and your website's files are in that subfolder. If you do not want the subfolder to appear as a part of the URL to your website, you can mask the subfolder from the URL by placing the following directives in the .htaccess file inside the public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

if You Can't Enter Your Domain Name then You Do Like This Include HTTPS -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

In the above lines you should replace the following:

domain-name.com - Type your domain name

folder - Type the name of the subfolder which has the website's files (in your case the name of the subfolder is theme.)

Comment: After Using This Code Not Working Other Folder Like Images Folder and Others

Comment: This is a different issue, I suppose the images and the other files were working correctly before. If so, I think the issue is that you reference the images/files through their relative URLs. Check these posts and see if they help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780562/images-wont-show-after-redirect-using-htaccess

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379119/htaccess-images-not-showing-after-rewriting

Comment: Images Folder Working But i Need To Use htaccess file for each folder..